# (Apache) Redirect https domain to port serve throw https

Tags: https, apache2, http-redirect

I have done redirection in apache before but in a simple way what I do is that enable rewrite module in apache server and then add the two ***.conf*** file in ***/etc/apache2/sites-available*** mentioned below

The below file is for redirecting HTTP request received throw domain to a specific port.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
ServerName test.domain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
# setup the proxy
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://localhost:3235/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3235/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =chat-dev.motivone.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The below file is for redirecting HTTPS request received throw domain to a specific port.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
ServerName test.domain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
# setup the proxy
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://localhost:3235/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3235/
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

this process just works fine when I run my server throws HTTP and change proxy to HTTP but when I run my server on https and then try to redirect it. its throw the error like

[image]

i am not sure what is wrong ay kind of help is appriciable thanks in advance